# Why can't the interface be implemented with pointer receivers

Tags: pointers, interface, go

I'm confused as to why this fails to compile with:

> > impossible type assertion:
> >          Faz does not implement Foo (Bar method has pointer receiver)

if I make the receiver for Faz.Bar a Faz value rather than a Faz pointer then it compiles fine, but I thought it was always better to have pointer receivers so values aren't being copied around?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    foo := New().(Faz)
    log.Println(foo)
}

type Foo interface {
    Bar() string
}

func New() Foo {
    return &Faz{}
}

type Faz struct {
}

func (f *Faz) Bar() string {
    return `Bar`
}
```

Comment: [See this post](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go).

Comment: As sort of a side note: the article referenced by @KerrekSB was helpful for me to understand that when Go complains "MyFoo does not implement Foo (Bar method has pointer receiver)", it doesn't mean that you _can't_ use a pointer receiver. It means that either _none_ of the methods of `MyFoo` that  implement `Bar` should have pointer receivers, or _all_ of them must. That's a different issue than @0xor1 was having, but others might find this question because they are mixing their receiver types (like I was) and not understanding the error they're getting.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Because it's `*Faz` not `Faz`.

```
func main() {
    foo := New().(*Faz)
    log.Println(foo)
}
```

Comment: They can be either *Faz or Faz but they all must match. Define them all Faz if you intend to `return Faz{}` or *Faz if you intend to `return &Faz{}`. How they maintain state is considered an implementation detail that you are basically hiding from the user.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer to this question needs to a more retrospective approach towards the grammar, and how would implement it through software engineering. *(Excuse the over simplification)*

---

First a quick flashback of what are `types`?
They are just memory blocks with compiler logic on top. What makes an `array` different from a `string` is what the compiler allows us to do with those memory blocks. (Think deeper and you may begin to realize the true difference between `strongly typed` and `dynamically typed` languages.)

Now next you need to realize that pointers are their own types per say. 
`*variable` is a different memory block (aka type) than `variable`. It's just that the compiler always assumes that content of `*variable` is always going to be an address to a memory block of type to the right of the declaration along with other restriction/features it imposes.

Then let's recap what an interface is.
*Pseudo-scientific definition*: A set of requirements for any first class citizen to be of a specific type. 
Translated to software engineering- any block of memory (types) that has the same memory structure (think back to *[structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)*) associated to it as described in a contract (`interface`) can be passed around as with the *type name* that the contract mentions.

---

Now you may begin to realize that when you say

`func (f *Faz) Bar() string` is `f`'s block of memory holding a function, where `f`'s type is *a pointer to `Faz`*

where areas

`func (f Faz) Bar() string` is `f`'s block of memory, where `f`'s type is `Faz`

So when you are saying that a variable of `*Faz` type is satisfying a contract, then how can you assume that a variable of `Faz` type will qualify as interface type in the code? Chose who satisfies your contract, and only that type can assume the interface type in your code.

Comment: I don't agree with your explanation, following program works (type *foo satisfies String() defined for type foo):package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type foo struct{}

func (f foo) String() string {
 return "111"
}

func main() {
 f := foo{}
 a := &foo{}
 var s fmt.Stringer
 s = a
 s = f
 fmt.Println(f.String(), a.String(), s)
}